# Merging up multiple rows in one row acc. to condition in SQL

Tags: sql

In SQL I have a query.This query is used to find financial ,administrative and FYI errors of an employee.These are different type of errors.

```
select i_empid,COUNT(i_empid) as claims_audited,sum( i_errcount ) as total_errors,
case when c_errtype = 'FINANCIAL' then SUM(i_errcount) else 0 End as financial_errors ,
case when c_errtype = 'ADMINISTRATIVE' then SUM(i_errcount) else 0 End as administrative_errors ,
case when c_errtype = 'FYI' then SUM(i_errcount) else 0 End as FYI_errors ,
case when c_errtype = 'FINANCIAL' then SUM(i_errcount) else 0 End/  sum( i_errcount ) as  financial_percent ,
case when c_errtype = 'ADMINISTRATIVE' then SUM(i_errcount) else 0 End/ sum( i_errcount)as administrative_percent,
case when c_errtype = 'FYI' then SUM(i_errcount) else 0 End /sum( i_errcount ) as FYI_percent
from    EL_Error_Mst
group by i_empid,c_errtype
```

Iam getting result set like this:

```
i_empid claims_audited  total_errors    financial_errors    administrative_errors   FYI_errors  financial_percent   administrative_percent  FYI_percent
13  1   1   0   1   0   0.000000    1.000000    0.000000
341 1   1   0   1   0   0.000000    1.000000    0.000000
665 2   2   0   2   0   0.000000    1.000000    0.000000
341 1   1   1   0   0   1.000000    0.000000    0.000000
```

But I want single row for each employee.How can I get This?

Comment: there is no DATE field in your sample

Comment: Can you please put your table structure and sample data. Other tables that are being used.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've edited your question significantly from the initial post, so here is a completely new answer.

There are a couple of things you might need to take into account:

- Your current query will return multiple rows per `i_empid` if any employees have multiple error types, as you are grouping by `c_errtype`
- If you want to calculate percentages without having to repeat your case when statements, you can nest the initial aggregation, and then run the calculation against the results
- For percentages you might want to cast as a float so that it doesn't round it to an integer

Here is a query that I think gets what you're after:

```
select  a.*,
        cast( financial_errors as float ) / total_errors as  financial_percent ,
        cast( administrative_errors as float ) / total_errors as administrative_percent,
        cast( FYI_errors as float) / total_errors as FYI_percent
from    (
          select  i_empid,
                  COUNT(i_empid) as claims_audited,
                  sum( i_errcount ) as total_errors,
                  sum( case when c_errtype = 'FINANCIAL' then i_errcount else 0 end ) as financial_errors,
                  sum( case when c_errtype = 'ADMINISTRATIVE' then i_errcount else 0 end ) as administrative_errors,
                  sum( case when c_errtype = 'FYI' then i_errcount else 0 end ) as FYI_errors
          from    EL_Error_Mst
          group by i_empid
        ) as a
```

[SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/654d2/4)

Answer (score 1):

```
select  date,
        emp_id,
        examiner_name,
        sum( claims_audited ) as claims_audited,
        sum( errorCount ) as total_errors,
        sum( case when error_type = 'FINANCIAL' then 1 else 0 end ) as financial_errors,
        sum( case when error_type = 'ADMINISTRATIVE' then 1 else 0 end ) as administrative_errors,
        financial_errors / total_errors as financial_percent,
        administrative_errors/ total_errors as financial_percent
from    table_name
group by date,
        emp_id,
        examiner_name
```

Comment: Which dbms accepts column aliases in select list expressions?

Comment: @jarlh, Teradata does, and since that's what I use in my day job I sometimes forget it isn't standard. Do you think I should update to use a sub query?